# Zurb Foundation 6 refresh after React re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, zurb-foundation

I'd like to use "orbit" plugin from Zurb Foundation Framework to display carousel.
I use React to component render.
First time all works because I call to jQuery(document).foundation();

But when react component is re-render (for example when I add new image) then Orbit isn't display. Call to `jQuery(document).foundation();` throw error that I use function on element where foundation already exists.

In Zurb 6 also doesn't exists option `.foundation('reflow')` or `.foundation('refresh')`

Any hints how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Can you please share the error?

Comment: Sure "`jquery.js:374 Tried to initialize responsive-toggle on an element that already has a Foundation plugin."` jQuery throw it

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `Foundation.reInit` function to reload foundation for a particular component.

In this case, you have to add

```
Foundation.reInit('orbit');
```

I thought the better place to add it is in `componentDidUpdate` method of your React.Component class